Google drive file uploading android
I'm currently develop an android app that user can backup their SMS and call history. I did successfully develop all backing up part and I'm stuck on cloud backup method. I'm trying to upload backup file to google drive, But I couldn't find right google drive api documentation. I searched on stack overflow questions and the answers are too old and also didn't work. So, Can you guide me.
I also tried searching google, chat gpt 3.5 free version. But nothing helps me. I'm using java to develop the app. Thank you. :)

What do you mean by "answers are too old"? Age alone doesn't make an answer useless or wrong. What happened when you tried implementing them? Which ones?

Thank you for your reply. I meant some answers are 8 years ago. I tried them and I always get errors.

what error? please provide more information, the code you tried, etc.

The problem is, there is nowhere a latest working code, how to connect to Google Drive from android and upload/download something. All codes are deprecated as they use GoogleSignIn. But no code with the new Authorization API. Google is changing they API's very often, but then they provide a very poor documentation
